# json_decode JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error when deecoding from POST data

Tags: php

This code works fine for me

```
 $input= '{"remoteRef":"RM4","competitionName":"Calgary 2012 - IVF World Sprint Champs","venue":"Calgary, Canada","startDate":"2012-08-11T00:00.00","finishDate":"2012-08-11T00:00.00","races":[{"remoteRef":"1001-0010303","raceNo":"216","eventName":"Adaptive Mixed - V6 500","roundName":"St. Final","roundNo":1,"roundCount":1,"scheduledStart":"2012-08-13T13:36.00","actualStart":"2012-08-13T14:28.08","isFinal":true,"lanes":[{"laneNo":"1","teamName":"Hawaii # 2","clubName":"Hawai\u0027i","placing":"3","officialTime":"3:00.58","officialTimeMs":86580580},{"laneNo":"2","teamName":"Rio Va´a","clubName":"Brazil","placing":"2","officialTime":"2:46.66","officialTimeMs":86566660},{"laneNo":"3","teamName":"Hawaii # 1","clubName":"Hawai\u0027i","placing":"1","officialTime":"2:46.43","officialTimeMs":86566430}],"raceState":"RESULT"}]}';

 $json = json_decode($input);

 var_dump($json);
```

But when I post the same data to my website and use the code below. I get a json decode error JSON_ERROR_UTF8

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json = json_decode($input);

var_dump($json);
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong to get that JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error?

Comment: examine $input and verify that it's utf-8 encoded JSON

Comment: I echo'd $input and cut and paste it into the top example. And it works. Maybe I have to do something about content-types? I am not sure

Comment: How are you constructing the JSON before sending it to the server, and how are you sending it to the server?

Comment: I'd try `json_decode(utf8_encode($input))` -  My guess is it's the Unicode apostrophe's causing you grief

Comment: the json is created in a java application, using gson library, I can post that code too if it helps. I just found it unusual I could cut and paste the jsonstring i received and decode it no problem, but when I post it, it fails

Comment: @bumperbox I think it's more likely that there is a least one additional character coming from `php://input` that gets lost or translated during the copy/paste (e.g. some trailing NULLs). Try `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` and compare the stated byte length with the actual byte length of the visible characters in the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

try base64 encode before posting and decode after getting..